# Анимация заполнения menu item при нажатии в Android

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, android-animation, menuitem

Есть Drawer Navigation. В нём menu, где при долгом нажатии на раздел (item) происходит затемнение фона этого раздела (возможно это называется ripple эффект).

Как возможно отключить эту анимацию или переопределить её? Пробовал выставить background transparent, но ситуацию не исправило. Также добавлял в drawable-v21 ресурс, где задавал свой ripple, тоже не дало эффекта.

Стили пунктам меню при нажатии задаю через отдельный селектор, где настройки по типу android:state_checked и так далее.

[image: Справа появляется дополнительный бэкграунд от нажатия]

Вот на фото справа сзади постепенно добавляется при нажатии фон, что нужно убрать

Answer (score 0):

Создайте селектор такого типа:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

И примените его в NavigaionView

```
app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_selector"
```